# Download page won't offer me the iso file for mac

Tags: files, mac, downloads, iso, macosx

The download page won't offer me the iso file for mac option, so when I try to install ubuntu, my mac doesn't recognise the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can access all the iso's directly:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/

Comment: The mac option would be on the [cdimage](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/) site.